# Only one Workspace in Gnome-Shell 3.10.4

Tags: gnome, compiz, workspaces

My gnome-shell seems to have only one workspace. I cannot switch to another workspace by using the Ctrl+Alt+Down/Up combination and using the Super Key always shows me one workspace only. If I attempt to open a program in a new workspace using the middle mousebutton i can observe there being 2 workspaces briefly but then the program gets moved to the upper one and the second one disappears.
I have already tried to use static workspaces using gnome-tweak-tool. This gives me multiple workspaces, but they all show the exact same content. They are not independent from eachother.
Furthermore I have found executing

```
compiz --replace
gnome-shell --replace
```

Gives me a gnome-shell with working workspaces.

Edit: Actually the workspace feature just disappeared as I opened a program. So scrap the part about it working.

Comment: Not happening to me; do you have any extension enabled?

Comment: gnome-tweak-tool says no extensions installed. I have already tried reinstalling gnome-shell twice to no avail. Its always the same.

Comment: I wonder if trying to run `compiz --replace` may have interfered with gnome-shell and mutter proper configuration. I don't know what effect that would have if you tried it. Note that gnome-shell only works with the mutter window manager, it will not work with compiz.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have fixed this problem, by disabling the option "Workspaces on primary display only" in the Gnome Tweak Tool.

Everything works again as expected.

Comment: having the same problem, this solved my problem

Comment: That seems to have worked for me, after restarting gnome shell. However, I like the feature of only having workspace on the primary display. Is there any other fix?

Comment: I have yet to find a fix for this. I know of no workarounds Im afraid.

Comment: same here :-S .... Gnome 3.22..,  this solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I switched to graphics driver nvidia-331. When I switched back to X.Org (nouveau) driver or to nvidia-331-updates, the workspaces again works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are running compiz, you need to enable the workspaces using the compiz session manager. See the answer on the link below:

```
http://askubuntu.com/questions/519651/add-workspaces-with-gnome-classic-and-ubuntu-14-04/519718#519718
```