# add workspaces with gnome classic and ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, workspaces, gnome-classic, workspace-switcher

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome classic.

I want to add 4 workspaces.
I right click into the workspaces (left-bottom) and go to preferences. I change the number of workspaces from 1 to 4 and close the window.
No workspaces are added and when I press to preferences again, I see a 1 not a 4.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Do you mean gnome-session-flashback instead of gnome classic ? If yes, you can do that by installing the compizconfig settings manager and plugins packages, i.e.

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins
```

You need to start the compizconfig settings manager found under

Appications -> System Tools -> Preferences

Once loaded, click on General Options and the Desktop Size tab to set the workspaces.

Comment: The plugin "Desktop Wall" offers keyboard binings for workspace switching.

Comment: Though `vertical size` not working, if `Desktop Wall` is not enabled

Answer (score 12):

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-plugins`

After installing CompizConfig Settings Manager it should be:

`Appications -> System Tools -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager`

A window will appear, accompanied by a Warning dialog. Click OK on the warning dialog.

Double-click General options on the other window.

Now click on Desktop Size. The default value is 1 (horizontal) x 1 (vertical). Change to whatever you would like to have. I chose 2 x 2 which was what I wanted, and it worked perfectly!

Comment: CompizConfig Settings Manager is not installed by default

Comment: This is exactly how it worked for me under 14.04.